# When is it ideal to use providedIn 'any'?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm building a very simple, lightweight and shareable package that contains some of my frequently used functions and classes.  A toolbox for angular if you will, and for my own projects.

One of my classes needs to be provided as a service. It follows a factory pattern and will in turn provide an instance of a class for which it resolves dependencies via constructor injection if a dependency array is supplied.  To do this, the factory itself has an injector injected into its own instance, which it will use to resolve the product's dependencies.

My question is: am I right to believe that I should use `providedIn: 'any'` for this factory, so that it is given an injector more appropriate to whatever module may be using the service?  And if not, when is it ideal to use `providedIn: 'any'`?

Comment: Never anymore I think. As far as I know, any will be deprecated (or already is?)

Comment: @MikeOne How do you figure?  The docs don't provide a deprecation warning, and they haven't replaced 'any' with anything else.  We're still using Injectable decorators afaik, which are supposed to give us control over which injectors will be used to supply a dependency, and without options we have no control.

Comment: Good question. Just tried to find it again but unsuccessful. Read it somewhere recently. Sorry I can’t be more helpful.

Comment: There it is.. https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedIn:%7E:text=%27any%27%20%3A%20Provides%20a%20unique%20instance%20in%20each%20lazy%20loaded%20module%20while%20all%20eagerly%20loaded%20modules%20share%20one%20instance.%20This%20option%20is%20DEPRECATED.